# jsp:param : name parameter can't accept dynamic data?

Tags: jsp

I'd like to set the "name" param to a jsp:param in a "dynamic-way", that is :

`<jsp:param value="<%=paramValue%>" name="<%=pageURL%>"/>`

instead of :

`<jsp:param value="<%=paramValue%>" name="page"/>`

Or a similar way to do it .. I just don't want to decide the url at runtime.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for the anwsers :)

Cheers

Comment: What are you using the `<jsp:param>` for?

Comment: i'm using it to pass params to a servlet, in a <jsp:forward>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's disallowed as per the [syntax reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828).

Just add another param.

```
<jsp:param name="page" value="<%=paramValue%>" />
<jsp:param name="url" value="<%=pageURL%>" />
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, *scriptlets* are not the best practice. Consider learning EL, those `${}` things, it's already over a decade the recommend way of accessing backend data in JSPs.

Comment: Alas, the world is awash with crappy out-of-date JSP books

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but by adding another param it doesn't solve my problem ^^ I just want to decide in a dynamic-style all my param's names. And thanks for the advice on ELs, i'll dig into right away :) @skaffman : well it's even worse with "crappy out-of-date" teachers

Comment: With EL you could easily pass a `Map` around as request attribute and use dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Expression Language too:

```
<jsp:param value="${paramValue}" name="page"/>
<jsp:param value="${pageURL}" name="url"/>
```